# why strlen() function is giving wrong value

Tags: c, input, string-length, strlen

I don't understand why `strlen()` is giving wrong value (ie: `9`) only for the first string. After that the values are coming correctly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int m, i, j;
    i = 2;
    j = 5;
    char a[i][j];
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)  {
        scanf("%s", a[i]);
    }
    m = strlen(a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", m); //here the problem is coming//
    m = strlen(a[1]);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    m = strlen(a[2]);
    printf("%d\n", m);

    return 0;
}
```

INPUT:

```
heyman
jack
bro
```

OUTPUT:

```
9
4
3
```

Comment: You can only have strings up to `4` characters because `j == 5`.

Comment: `heyman` is writing out of bounds.

Comment: why only 4 as j=5 i.e-(0-5) which will give me max 6 character to input.?? help?

Comment: @fly_high `j=5` will give you 5 characters to write, from `0` to `4`, but strings need to have an additional character `\0` at the end otherwise `C` doesn't know that the string is actually over. That means that from your maximum length you have to subtract `1` to account for this terminator `\0`

Comment: @fly_high `a[5]` means you have positions `a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]` available, i.e. `5` spaces not that the array will go up to `a[5]`

Comment: ok ok actually i was understanding in a way of as like rows as in row i have written a[2] so it goes from 0-2(0,1,2) but this is not in the case of column right....?@John Smith

Comment: Rows and columns are the same. An array `a[2]` has only 2 elements with index `0..1`.

Comment: ok ok now i get it...

Comment: Please remember, in C, offsets start with 0, so the valid index into an array is 0...(number of elements in array -1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each row of `a` is only 5 bytes. When you read `heyman` into `a[0]`, it overflows into `a[1]`. So you have:

```
a[0] = "heyma"
a[1] = "n\0"
```

Then when you read into `a[1]`, you have

```
a[0] = "heyma"
a[1] = "jack\0"
```

Notice that there's no null terminator in `a[0]`. So when you call `strlen(a[0])`, it goes past the end of `a[0]` and continues searching in `a[1]` for the null byte. There are 5 bytes in `a[0]` and 4 bytes in `a[1]`, so the length is 9. Technically, this is undefined behavior, but this is what happens in actual implementations because 2-dimensional arrays are contiguous.

In addition, when you read into `a[2]` you're completely outside the `a` array, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: I wonder if overflowing from `a[0]` into `a[1]` is ub (obviously doing anything with `a[2]` is).

Comment: @PaulHankin I think I've read conflicting answers about it.

Comment: wow that was really interesting and i got all of the idea....thanks @Barmar

Comment: Appendix J.2 in the standard explicitly lists this kind of out of bounds multi-dimensional array access as an example of undefined behaviour: `An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5])`

Comment: It is UB when it overflows into `a[1]`

Answer (score 7):

Since your array has length `[2][5]` you can store a maximum of `2` words of length `4`, every word also has the terminating character `\0` in addition to its letters.

You having as input `heyman` means you are writing too many letters and don't have enough space to also store the `\0`. Either try with a shorter word or change your length from `5` to `7`.

Also you are storing `3` words in your array of length `2`, the length refers to the number of elements stored not to the number you can go up to. Length `2` will have available positions `0` and `1` so when you are passing as input the third word you are trying to write outside of the array bounds.

Comment: He needs to change the length to at least 7: heyman has 6 characters plus null

Comment: @Barmar oh yeah you're right, for some reason i counted 5 characters in heyman instead of 6